# Get price from database on click event

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, smarty

Im new to using html, javascript, php and Smarty.

I would like to know how to get my price to display if a product is selected.

My database connection works i can display the products , but when i select the product i want his price to display in a form.

**.php**

```
<?php

$new = ['product_id','product_category','product_price','product_quantity','product_about','product_color'];

//Database connection
 $db = mysqli_connect('xxx','xxx','xxx','xxx')
 or die('Error connecting to MySQL server.');

//access Smarty template engine
require_once('Smarty-3.1.30/libs/Smarty.class.php');

$smarty = new Smarty();
$smarty->template_dir = 'views';
$smarty->compile_dir = 'tmp';


//query product page
$query = "SELECT * FROM cs_shop";
mysqli_query($db, $query) or die('Error querying database.');

$result = mysqli_query($db, $query);


//query an array of products
$rows = array();

 //loop start
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $rows[] = array(
        'product_id' => $row['product_id'],
        'product_category' => $row['product_category'],
        'product_price' => $row['product_price'],
        'product_quantity' => $row['product_quantity'],
        'product_about' => $row['product_about'],
        'product_color' => $row['product_color']
    );
}

//db collect data
$smarty->assign('row', $rows); 
//template
$smarty->display('index.tpl');

mysqli_close($db);

?>
```

**.js**

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function () {
  //your code here
  $(function () {
        $('#products').change(function () {
        $('#priceInput').val($('#products option:selected').data('data-price'));
    });
});

});

</script>
```

**.tpl**

```
<select name="productID" id="products"> 

    {foreach from=$row item="item"}

      <option value="$item['product_category']" data-price="$item['product_price']" >{$item['product_category'] } : {$item['product_price'] }</option>

    {/foreach} 

</select> 



 <form>     
    Price : <input value="" name="Price" type="text" id="priceInput" disabled="disabled">       
  </form>
```

I would like to know what i am missing here? thanks in advance

Comment: You may need curly braces around the php value in `data-price="$item['product_price']"` to actualy print the price value into the template -> `data-price="{$item['product_price']}"`

Comment: i added it but nothing displays..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#products').change(function () {
        $('#priceInput').val($('#products option:selected').data('price'));
    });
});
```

Comment: @Ylama try it now, I edited. Just copy & paste literally. Is working for me on jsfiddle.

Comment: not working ey, tried it but it just displays an empty input field.

Comment: i think the js is fine, its more to do with my smarty template syntax... does that look fine to you?

Comment: If you inspect dropdown can you see data-price attribute fine?

Comment: in my <select> dropdown i see the data-price attribute perfectly.

Comment: So if you can see data-price attribute I think is js problem. Have you fixed it?

Comment: i updated my question, for the select i can see the data-price but for the input (on the .tpl which i added new) i cant see the data-price, i call this id from js

Comment: First, remove `$(function () {})` from your js because you have `$(document).ready(function () {})` which is the same. Then, try changing `$('#priceInput').val` for an alert in order to see if is working properly.

Comment: i used ur js just as is not working, then removed  $(function () {}) from js, not working, and if i use the wrong syntax it shows an error on console, that means it does read the js?

Comment: To see if your js is working just write an alert just after document ready, for example: `alert("Test");`. If not working, you know your js is not running. Where do you have placed js code?

Comment: it shows the alert, thanks, so i know thats working right? so the problem is somewhere within the syntax? just thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: If it shows the alert that means is working. Can you check console log for errors? I tried on jsfiddle and is working properly... https://jsfiddle.net/q4cL3kcm/1/

Comment: thanks for the help, GOT IT WORKING, i changed this part as i did previously,   val($('#products option:selected').data('data-price'))  to val($('#products option:selected').data('price')), i read up on js. data and realized i was calling 'data' twice... i had it like yours but when i read up and understood it made more sense rolling back as it was, thanks again!

Comment: Glad it works, but should work too with `.attr('data-price')`

Comment: i want to agree with you but like i just tried it and not working... but ill go check out why not.. just to understand better and get back to you.

Comment: somewhere i made a mistake, becuase your code is working now,, maybe just a suntax error i dont knwo, thanks a million!! upvoted your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Becuase i used .data on my java script i read function the data twice, and that was my mistake.. so the fix looks like this -->

**.js**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#products').change(function () {
        var price = $('#products option:selected').data('price');
    $('#priceInput').val(price);

});

});
```

So basically to my understanding when it reads 'price' in my .tpl it adds 'data' as value so it would look like "data-price". What i had was "data-data-price".